# I'm trying to print the count for even digits in an integer, but somehow the code is not printing anything after I run it. What's the cause?

Tags: java

I started to learn java few days ago, and I'm having trouble with this in-class exercise. Somehow when I run the code it does not produce any output.

```
public class FourthClass {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            int integer = 2222;
            int counter = 0;
            while(integer >=0){ 
                if(integer %2 ==0){
                    counter++;
                }
                integer = integer/10;
            }
            System.out.println(counter);
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try printing the value of `integer` in your loop.

Comment: When would you expect `integer` to  be less than 0?  (Using a debugger would have made the issue clear *very* quickly.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop condition is wrong. Your condition says to enter the loop when `integer` is greater than 0 or equals to 0 . After 4 iterations the value of `integer` becomes 0 and loop continues. Remove the `=` condition it will work.